# Need to see Flat View of Document Set in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, caml

I need to be able to display a flat view of all files in a Document Set in SharePoint 2010. Nothing I have tried works. I would like to just modify the default CAML code in the page view in SharePoint Designer. Here's what I have so far:

```
  <View Name="{957D4745-05AA-42B4-B61D-D474E035D394}" Scope="RecursiveAll" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="All Documents" Url="/home/Communications/FinalDocuments/Forms/AllItems.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png">
  <Query>
    <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef"/>
    </OrderBy>
  </Query>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/>
    <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Modified"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Editor"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Newsletter_x0020_ID0"/>
    <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
  </ViewFields>
  <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
  <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
  <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Used the built in functionality to hide folders. And then I filtered out the view to hide Document Set folders. Worked like a charm. Didn't have to touch the code.